# Did a Vice President ever cast a tie-breaking vote against his own party?

Tags: united-states, senate, vice-president

The Vice President is theoretically allowed to vote according to his own conscience, just as all other members of the Congress. But did a situation ever occur where the Vice President cast a tie-breaking vote against the party of which they were currently a member?

Comment: Before the adoption of the [12th Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelfth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) in 1804, the President and Vice President were not necessarily from the same party. It's quite likely some VPs form this era cast tie breaking votes against the party of the President.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit  There was only one vice president of a different party than the president prior to 1804, Thomas Jefferson was VP to John Adams from 1801 to 1805.  The only other time that happened was Andrew Johnson (Democrat) in Abraham Lincoln's administration (Republican), but technically they ran on the Union ticket (1864).  They had no congressional party.

Comment: that still wouldn't fit the question: "against the party of which they were currently a member" I think a better guess would be under either Roosevelt, one switched parties and the other switched VP's twice. So the VP might be assumed to be at odds with the president, or the administration at odds with the party. I don't know my history well enough to even name the VP's though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, in January 1832 when Vice President John C. Calhoun (who had served as VP under John Quincy Adams and Andrew Jackson) cast tie-breaking votes on two different occasions to kill President Jackson’s nomination of Martin Van Buren to be the U.S. Minister to England.

Comment: Good catch. Also, Good call on Calhoun's part. Van Buren was one of the more mediocre U.S. politicians.

Comment: It's worth noting that the US was in the middle of a realignment then.  While both Jackson and Calhoun had been Democratic Republicans, Calhoun was a Nullifier in 1832 while Jackson was a Democrat or Jacksonian.  So Calhoun wasn't necessarily acting against his party.  He was a different party from the president.  A third example (along with Jefferson and Johnson) of a VP not of the same party as the president.